# C# Webclient cannot download api.github.com pages

Tags: c#, .net, github, webclient

Visual Studios 2019 C# .NET Framework 4.6

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
wc.DownloadFile(new System.Uri("https://api.github.com/repos/[Username]/[Reponame]/releases/latest"), "name.json");
```

I want my app to check for updates from its own github repo but the above code is unable to download the latest release page from github api.

It is strange that I am able to download everything else including raw files from github using the same code as above but not pages from api.github.com

**EDIT: The Github Repo I am trying this with is not private.**

No compile time error. Below are some screenshots of debug runtime exceptions:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: `cannot download` is not descriptive enough to make any sense. Edit your question to include details like exception, response contents or other observations to help us understand why you think it is unable to download content from said url.

Comment: There is no compiler error. But on debug runtime, it breaks with error 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. api.github.com need the `User-Agent` header in requests.

Just had to change the code to this: (Only added the fourth line)

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "request");
wc.DownloadFile(new System.Uri("https://api.github.com/repos/[Username]/[Reponame]/releases/latest"), "name.json");
```